# selecting li element next to other li using document.(property)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm using a pub/sub solution called ably.io to subscribe and publish values for real-time purposes.
The way I have it set up is I'm assigning a dynamic id to each listing in ngFor. This is so that I can identify the correct listing to assign a value from ably.io subscribe

`document.getElementById(message.data.auctionId).innerHTML = "$" + message.data.lastBid;`

This works perfectly. I just need to access the li next to it now so that I can give it the correct value.

The goal is to grab the lastBidderName from ably.io and assign it to dynamic auctionId listing so that it updates in real-time too and not just on browser refresh.

In order for this to work, I would need to do access the child element class called lastBidderName after finding the correct auctionId. Then I can assign message.data.lastBidderName from ably.io to it.

How can I change the second example below to access child element correctly?

```
channel.subscribe(message => {

  document.getElementById(message.data.auctionId).innerHTML =
    "$" + message.data.lastBid;

    document.querySelector(
    "message.data.auctionId > lastBidderName"
  ).innerHTML = message.data.lastBidderName;

});
```

html

```
<li>Current Bid:
    <span id="{{auction.id}}" class="currentBid">
      ${{auction.currentBid}}
    </span>
</li>
<li>Bidder: 
    <span id="lastBidderName">
       {{auction.lastBidderName}}
    </span>
 </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you add Ids on both of items like this

```
<li>Current Bid:
    <span id="auction-{{auction.id}}" class="currentBid">
      ${{auction.currentBid}}
    </span>
</li>
<li>Bidder: 
    <span id="bidder-{{auction.id}}" class="lastBidderName">
       {{auction.lastBidderName}}
    </span>
 </li>
```

and in .ts

```
channel.subscribe(message => {

  document.getElementById(
`auction-${message.data.auctionId}`).innerHTML =
    "$" + message.data.lastBid;

    document.getElementById(
   `bidder-${message.data.auctionId}`
  ).innerHTML = message.data.lastBidderName;

});
```

And One question.

Why you don’t update the action object?

Comment: That's really clever! It works now thanks. I'm not sure what you mean by action object. If you're talking about publishing the value to the ably.io, that happens somewhere else.

Comment: @user6680 I mean you can just find the action which id is equal to `message.data.auctionId` and just do  `auction. currentBid = message.data.lastBid` and  `auction.lastBidderName = message.data.lastBidderName`

Comment: I guess I could. I was following documentation and I found an example in one of the ably.io tutorials that did the document.getElementById.innerHtml. It seemed to work really well for me so I never considered alternative solutions lol

Comment: @user6680 let me create the simple example

Comment: Sure. I'm open to other solutions if you wanna give me an example

Comment: @user6680 here is the simple example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fqossr Please check the link.

Comment: I can see what you're doing. I appreciate the example. Are there any concerns with using document.getElementById?

Comment: @user6680 Angular recommend avoid manupulation with DOM elements,here is the angular documentation connected with this https://angular.io/guide/security#direct-use-of-the-dom-apis-and-explicit-sanitization-calls

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I went ahead and changed it to look like this. https://pastebin.com/VuDCuL78  Seems to be working well. Thanks again!